App launch icon click causes all activities to be destroyed
In our app, there are several activities.
When the user opens MainActivity-> EventActivity-> EventRegsiterActivity, and then clicks the home button we have an inconsistency behaviour.
When the user opens a recent app view and re-opens our app they would end up on EventRegsiterActivity, however, if the user clicks on the app icon then the app would destroy both EventActivity and EventRegsiterActivity and reopens our MainActivity. How to prevent this and copy logic that we have to a recent app?
For more context, we have android:launchMode="singleInstancePerTask" for MainActivity and none of these flags set to true
        android:excludeFromRecents="false"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch = "false"


You have to use android:launchMode="singleTask" instead of singleInstancePerTask

I just tested and it works the same way with singleTask and with no flag it is just the same but with different animation

can you explain more about when user clicks on the app icon -- which app icon? The one on the Home screen or the app icon in the Recent screen, also called the Overview screen? maybe posting a screenshot will be more helpful to understand

my app icon I mean just an icon from launcher like here
